# Vagrant ssh encountered an unknown error

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible

I was trying to run vagrant up for an existing vagrant setup. I get this following error:

```
PLAY [main] ******************************************************************* 

    GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
    fatal: [xxx.xxx.xx.xx] => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue

    TASK: [install python-software-properties] ************************************ 
    FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting


    PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
               to retry, use: --limit @/Users/mdobrenko/playbook.retry

    xxx.xxx.xx.xx              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   

    Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
    visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

Running vagrant -vvvv up reveals:

```
Mareks-MBP:rsvp_vagrant mdobrenko$ sudo vagrant -vvvv up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise32' is up to date...
==> default: VirtualBox VM is already running.
==> default: Checking for host entries
Mareks-MBP:rsvp_vagrant mdobrenko$ sudo vagrant destroy
    default: Are you sure you want to destroy the 'default' VM? [y/N] y
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
==> default: Removing hosts
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'ansible' provisioner...
Mareks-MBP:rsvp_vagrant mdobrenko$ sudo vagrant -vvvv up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/precise32'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise32' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: rsvp_vagrant_default_1431710679543_35240
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2200 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
    default: VirtualBox Version: 4.3
==> default: Checking for host entries
==> default: adding to (/etc/hosts) : 192.168.33.10  rsvp  # VAGRANT: 6778d1189c76a655929c20349162f9c4 (default) / 4d4353fa-c6e5-4346-b003-78d02ed54989
==> default: adding to (/etc/hosts) : 192.168.33.10  rsvp.dev  # VAGRANT: 6778d1189c76a655929c20349162f9c4 (default) / 4d4353fa-c6e5-4346-b003-78d02ed54989
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/mdobrenko/Sites/rsvp_vagrant
    default: /srv/rsvp_v2 => /Users/mdobrenko/Sites/rsvp_vagrant/vagrant
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible...

PLAY [main] ******************************************************************* 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
fatal: [192.168.33.10] => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue

TASK: [install python-software-properties] ************************************ 
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting


PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/Users/mdobrenko/playbook.retry

192.168.33.10              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

I am running a hashicorp/precise 32 box, and the IP address in my config file is 192.168.33.10.

**EDIT:**

After editing my vagrantfile -> ansible.verbose = 'vvvv'
This was the output of sudo vagrant up:

```
Mareks-MBP:rsvp_vagrant mdobrenko$ sudo vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/precise32'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise32' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: rsvp_vagrant_default_1431727399798_16186
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2200 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
    default: VirtualBox Version: 4.3
==> default: Checking for host entries
==> default: adding to (/etc/hosts) : 192.168.33.10  rsvp  # VAGRANT: b9809e905749d56ff4836d1021c101f9 (default) / 504dd053-7a44-42ce-af87-24331dc6783d
==> default: adding to (/etc/hosts) : 192.168.33.10  rsvp.dev  # VAGRANT: b9809e905749d56ff4836d1021c101f9 (default) / 504dd053-7a44-42ce-af87-24331dc6783d
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/mdobrenko/Sites/rsvp_vagrant
    default: /srv/rsvp_v2 => /Users/mdobrenko/Sites/rsvp_vagrant/vagrant
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible...
ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ansible-playbook --private-key=/Users/mdobrenko/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key --user=vagrant --inventory-file=inventory -vvvv --limit='all' provisions/playbook.yml

PLAY [main] ******************************************************************* 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
<192.168.33.10> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<192.168.33.10> REMOTE_MODULE setup
<192.168.33.10> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/Users/mdobrenko/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentityFile="/Users/mdobrenko/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 192.168.33.10 /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1431727421.02-64963608760193 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1431727421.02-64963608760193 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1431727421.02-64963608760193'
fatal: [192.168.33.10] => SSH encountered an unknown error. The output was:
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/Users/mdobrenko/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-192.168.33.10-22-vagrant" does not exist
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.33.10 [192.168.33.10] port 22.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: timeout: 10000 ms remain after connect
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/mdobrenko/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/mdobrenko/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mdobrenko/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
write: Broken pipe


TASK: [install python-software-properties] ************************************ 
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting


PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/Users/mdobrenko/playbook.retry

192.168.33.10              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
Mareks-MBP:rsvp_vagrant mdobrenko$
```

Vagrant File:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
  # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
  # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  config.vm.hostname = 'rsvp'
  config.hostsupdater.aliases = ["rsvp.dev"]
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # If true, then any SSH connections made will enable agent forwarding.
  # Default value: false
  # config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"
  config.vm.synced_folder "vagrant/", "/srv/rsvp_v2", :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"]

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Don't boot with headless mode
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM. For example to change memory:
  #   vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you're using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Enable provisioning with CFEngine. CFEngine Community packages are
  # automatically installed. For example, configure the host as a
  # policy server and optionally a policy file to run:
  #
  # config.vm.provision "cfengine" do |cf|
  #   cf.am_policy_hub = true
  #   # cf.run_file = "motd.cf"
  # end

    config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.verbose = 'vvvv'
      ansible.limit = 'all'
      ansible.inventory_path = 'inventory'
      ansible.playbook = "provisions/playbook.yml"
    end

  #
  # You can also configure and bootstrap a client to an existing
  # policy server:
  #
  # config.vm.provision "cfengine" do |cf|
  #   cf.policy_server_address = "10.0.2.15"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with Puppet stand alone.  Puppet manifests
  # are contained in a directory path relative to this Vagrantfile.
  # You will need to create the manifests directory and a manifest in
  # the file default.pp in the manifests_path directory.
  #
  # config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
  #   puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
  #   puppet.manifest_file  = "default.pp"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with chef solo, specifying a cookbooks path, roles
  # path, and data_bags path (all relative to this Vagrantfile), and adding
  # some recipes and/or roles.
  #
  # config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
  #   chef.cookbooks_path = "../my-recipes/cookbooks"
  #   chef.roles_path = "../my-recipes/roles"
  #   chef.data_bags_path = "../my-recipes/data_bags"
  #   chef.add_recipe "mysql"
  #   chef.add_role "web"
  #
  #   # You may also specify custom JSON attributes:
  #   chef.json = { mysql_password: "foo" }
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with chef server, specifying the chef server URL,
  # and the path to the validation key (relative to this Vagrantfile).
  #
  # The Opscode Platform uses HTTPS. Substitute your organization for
  # ORGNAME in the URL and validation key.
  #
  # If you have your own Chef Server, use the appropriate URL, which may be
  # HTTP instead of HTTPS depending on your configuration. Also change the
  # validation key to validation.pem.
  #
  # config.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
  #   chef.chef_server_url = "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/ORGNAME"
  #   chef.validation_key_path = "ORGNAME-validator.pem"
  # end
  #
  # If you're using the Opscode platform, your validator client is
  # ORGNAME-validator, replacing ORGNAME with your organization name.
  #
  # If you have your own Chef Server, the default validation client name is
  # chef-validator, unless you changed the configuration.
  #
  #   chef.validation_client_name = "ORGNAME-validator"
end
```

Any idea what the problem is? I'm not quite sure why this would happen, as it worked fine just a few months ago -- I haven't touched this project in a while.

Comment: Your provisioning failed, but the box should be up anyways. What happens when you try to SSH in with `vagrant ssh`?

Comment: It seems to ssh into vagrant without issue.. that's very odd... The laravel project I'm working on does not function correctly (I try to access the root URL and it won't load)

Comment: Try setting `ansible.verbose = 'vvvv'` in your [Vagrantfile](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/ansible.html). When you do it on the `vagrant up` command line, the argument is going to Vagrant, not Ansible.

Comment: Edited my post above -- perhaps this output can help figure out what's wrong

Comment: Another question, how come you're running vagrant commands with sudo? Shouldn't be necessary on your Mac. Maybe that's affecting it somehow, like a missing environment variable or something from ~/.ssh?

Comment: I was under the impression that you had to run sudo every time you tried to do so with vagrant... Always have in the past, and it worked fine at the time with sudo.

Comment: Actually, running it without sudo results in this output: http://pastebin.com/zdygh8B8

Comment: What does your `Vagrantfile` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I feel somewhat silly because I ended up resolving my own errors by working on something that wasn't exactly related to the project..

Essentially the other day I ran into some SSH key configuration issues -- it seems like one of my keys was doing something really weird. I created new keys, got rid of the old ones, updated config for my web servers, etc.

Today when re-visting the thread, I realized that 'vagrant up' runs just fine...

In the past, I always had to run 'sudo' because I would get some sort of strange errors indicating I didn't have permission.

Now I am able to run it without sudo, and it works like a charm.

Thanks to all those that contributed!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, sorry but I couldn't post as a comment to your answer.

Anyway if this is a permission related issue then it might be because at some point you ran vagrant with sudo.

Vagrant then creates files as a root user and any future attempts will run into permission problems.

Just chowning the .vagrant in your project folder to the current user should work, although you might also have to chown the .vagrant.d folder in your home directory.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, since we don't have much details about your Vagrantfile or your ssh configuration, but you probably should not run `vagrant up` as `sudo`.

If running `vagrant up` instead of `sudo vagrant up` doesn't solve your problem, please post the result of the `vagrant ssh-config` command and the Ansible provisioning section from your Vagrantfile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- I decided to just give you the bounty since I couldn't do anyone else.